# Unit testing scope function

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I can't seem to figure out how to properly unit test this function. Nomatter what `$scope.registerFail` is equal to `true`. I am pretty sure this is because the service call is getting called asynchronously but I'm unsure how to handle that.

Heres is my unit test

```
it('should fail', function(){
    $scope.registerForm={};
    $scope.registerForm.$valid = true;
    $scope.registerFail = true;
    $scope.register();
    expect($scope.registerFail).toEqual(false);
});
```

And this is my function:

```
$scope.register = function () {
    var vm = this;
    if (vm.registerForm.$valid) {

        var names = vm.user.fullName.split(' '),
            first_name = names[0],
            last_name = '',
            payload;

        //Parse full name into first and last name 
        if (names.length > 1) {
            first_name = vm.user.fullName.substr(0, vm.user.fullName.length - names[names.length - 1].length - 1);
            last_name = names[names.length - 1];
        }

        payload = {
            email: vm.user.email,
            password: vm.user.password,
            password_confirmation: vm.user.password_confirmation,
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,
            terms_and_conditions: vm.user.terms_and_conditions,
            over_13: vm.user.over_13,
            ens_weekly_updates: vm.user.ens_weekly_updates,
            referrer_id: null
        };

        serverAuthenticationService.registerUser(payload).then(function(response){
            $scope.registerFail = false;
            $modalInstance.close();
            $state.go('business-profile.details');
        }, function (reason) {
            $scope.registerFail = true;
            angular.forEach(reason.data.errors, function (error) {
              error.field = error.field.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + error.field.substring(1);
              $scope.registerErrors = error.field + ' ' + error.info + '.';
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: From my reading it looks like I need to simulate the service call and not actually do it.

Comment: That's right. You will have to mock it out to return a promise object, and not actually run the service. When you are unit testing a piece of code, all external dependencies should be mocked out.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: Looks ugly in comment, but something like:- var deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.resolve();
spyOn(serverAuthenticationService, 'registerUser').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

Comment: I cannot see how you are using the returned response from the service in case of success.

Comment: @AbhishekJain: or much simpler: `spyOn(serverAuthenticationService, 'registerUser').and.returnValue($q.when());`

Comment: hahaha... true... actually I pasted the code from a real example in my project that was doing a bit more stuff.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time trying to make it synchronize. I have the results being saved in a variable that I use for my expect and its returning undefined everytime.

Comment: `serverAuthenticationService.registerUser($scope.user).then(function(returnFromPromise){ result = returnFromPromise; });`

Comment: and this is in my beforeEach `spyOn(serverAuthenticationService, 'registerUser').and.returnValue($q.when(false)); `

Comment: I think you will have to do $scope.$apply to actually get angular to execute the then function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
it('should fail', function(){
    spyOn(serverAuthenticationService, 'registerUser').and.returnValue($q.when(false));
    $scope.registerForm={};
    $scope.registerForm.$valid = true;
    $scope.registerFail = true;
    $scope.register();
    $scope.$apply(); // Forces $q.promise then callbacks to be called
    expect($scope.registerFail).toEqual(false);
});
```

[Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416403/how-to-unit-test-an-angularjs-promise-chain-using-httpbackend) for a similar SO answer for detailed explanation.